# Is a switch-case structure the fastest way to check a significant amount of regex expressions?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

To solve a problem of (regex-)detecting multiple entries, the switch/case approach seems better than the if/else approach both from a readability and a efficacy (speed, memory usage) point of view. But is it still the case when the number of cases to check increases?

Is a switch/case sentence of more than 20 cases (and more than 10 breaks) still the most efficient way in terms of speed and memory usage to solve that?

Example code:

```
for (var i in pieces) { // each pieces[i] is an unknown text
    switch (true) {
        case /^\"?Accession\"?/.test(pieces[i]):
        case /^\"?Protein IDs\"?/.test(pieces[i]):
            numeration[0] = i; // an array to store the "column" location
            break;
        case /^\"?Description\"?/.test(pieces[i]):
        case /^\"?Protein names\"?/.test(pieces[i]):
            numeration[1] = i;
            break;
        //etcetcetc...
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

## First things first

First, its better if you combine cases together as much as possible.

```
case /^\"?(Protein IDs|Accession)\"?/.test(pieces[i]):
```

this both has added performance and reduce memory usage.

## Switch vs If/else

> The switch statement is often cited in other programming languages as
>   the hands-down better option for evaluating multiple conditions. This
>   isn’t because of the nature of the switch statement, but rather
>   because of how compilers are able to optimize switch statements for
>   faster evaluation. Since most JavaScript engines don’t have such
>   optimizations, performance of the switch statement is mixed.
>
> Firefox handles switch statements very well, with each condition’s
>   evaluation executing in roughly the same amount of time regardless of
>   the order in which they are defined. That means the case of value
>   equal to 0 will take roughly the same amount of time to execute as
>   when value is 9. Other browsers, however, aren’t nearly as good.
>   Internet Explorer, Opera, Safari, and Chrome all show noticeable
>   increases in the execution time as you get deeper into the switch
>   statement. Those increases, however, are smaller than the increases
>   experienced with each additional condition of an if statement. You can
>   therefore improve the performance of switch statements by ordering the
>   conditions in decreasing rate of frequency (the same as if statement
>   optimization).

so i write an if statement then! but wait.

## Optimizing If statements

instead of writing:

```
if (value == 0){
    return result0;
} else if (value == 1){
    return result1;
} else if (value == 2){
    return result2;
} else if (value == 3){
    return result3;
} else if (value == 4){
    return result4;
} else if (value == 5){
    return result5;
} else if (value == 6){
    return result6;
} else if (value == 7){
    return result7;
} else if (value == 8){
    return result8;
} else if (value == 9){
    return result9;
} else {
    return result10;
}
```

You can write something like this, so the worst case isnt as bad as evaluating 9 conditions:

```
if (value < 6){

if (value < 3){
    if (value == 0){
        return result0;
    } else if (value == 1){
        return result1;
    } else {
        return result2;
    }
} else {
    if (value == 3){
        return result3;
    } else if (value == 4){
        return result4;
    } else {
        return result5;
    }
}

} else {

if (value < 8){
    if (value == 6){
        return result6;
    } else {
        return result7;
    }
} else {
    if (value == 8){
        return result8;
    } else if (value == 9){
        return result9;
    } else {
        return result10;
    }

}
```

Source: http://archive.oreilly.com/pub/a/server-administration/excerpts/even-faster-websites/writing-efficient-javascript.html

Comment: Ok, then I understand that there's nothing wrong with a switch/case statement with a lot of entries? (regarding the regex combination, in my particular case I need to keep them separated to facilitate readability later on, but I completely agree on your point)